# Как подключить модуль с анонимной функцией в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, javascript

**file.js**

```
 module.exports = (function(){
    var _num;

    this.Test = function(){
        // ...
    };

    this.Test.prototype = {
        setNum: function(n){
            _num = n
        },
        getNum: function(){
            return _num
        }
    }

    })()
```

**main.js**

```
var Test = require('path.file.js');

var test = new Test(); // так не работает.

// Вопрос: как правильно подключать анонимную функцию?
```

Comment: Не работает что? В вашем случае это что-то вроде new (new Test()).Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж вам так хочется анонимку (непонятно зачем), то делается так:

```
module.exports=function(){
        this.var=1;
        this.test=function() {
                console.log(this.var);
        }
        this.testAdd=function(a) {
                a=parseInt(a)||0;
                return this.var+=a;
        }
};
```

а нормально делается так:

```
module.exports=Test;

function Test(){};
Test.prototype.var=1;
Test.prototype.test=function() {
        console.log(this.var);
}
Test.prototype.testAdd=function(a) {
        a=parseInt(a)||0;
        return this.var+=a;
}
```

Comment: @eicto, спасибо! Я, видно, к ночи уже устал и спросил, находясь в полубреду:)  
Хотел создать анонимную функцию, чтобы облегчить доступ к приватным свойствам, а забыл, что этого и не нужно, так как модуль расматривается, как объект.

Comment: @vas, с "приватными" свойствами поосторожнее, т.к. внешний scope у двух инстансов одного объекта - одинаковый.

Comment: т.е. вот такое имеет очень ограниченное применение

    module.exports=Test;

    var n=0;

    function Test(){};
    Test.prototype.test=function() {
        console.log(n);
    }
    Test.prototype.testAdd=function(a) {
        a=parseInt(a)||0;
        return n+=a;
    }

Comment: @eicto, вот именно по этому я и вернулся к анонимной функции, но потом проверил и оказалось, что с модулями можно делать просто var prop = value и потом два инстенса имеют разные свойства prop.

Comment: Test=require("./test.js");
    var test1=new Test,test2=new Test;
    test1.testAdd(2);
    test2.test(); //2

Comment: Вот так можно в простом случае делать, если не страшна подмена instance

    module.exports=Test;

    var n={},inst=0;

    function Test(){
        this.instanceId=inst++;
        n[this.instanceId]=0;
    };
    Test.prototype.test=function() {
        console.log(n[this.instanceId]);
    }
    Test.prototype.testAdd=function(a) {
        a=parseInt(a)||0;
        return n[this.instanceId]+=a;
    }